# Typescript 2.0 error: Build:Unknown extension for file 'en-US'. Only .ts and d.ts extensions allowed

Tags: typescript

I just made an upgrade to **TypeScript 2.0** version. I then created a simple
**HTML Application with TypeScript** project in **Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise** 
to check if everything was running fine. 
The **app.ts** was transpiled to **app.js** on save with no error, though when I tried
to compile the solution I ended with an error saying:

***Build:Unknown extension for file: 'en-US'. Only .ts and d.ts extensions are allowed.***

I never encountered this type of error before. [Maybe a bad path location reference...],  so any help on how to fix this would be appreciated. Thank's

Comment: Last time I saw this kind of error, it was because I tell typescript to compile `foo.component` instead of `foo.component.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

***Problem was solved***!!! **Visual Studio 2015** must have been pointing to wrong **tsc** location path. I first made sure to clean up any previous conflicting existing versions. I then re-installed **TypeScript_Dev14Full.exe** [Product **version 2.0.3.0**] and that did the trick for me.